Discrepancy between Uniswap V3 liquidity ratio and USD value ratio on uniswap v3
I'm calculating liquidity for a Uniswap V3 pool and have encountered a discrepancy. I'm hoping someone can help me understand what's going on or if I'm making a mistake.
The situation:
I calculated the liquidity for my position using standard Uniswap V3 formulas (code below).
I used the Oku API to get the liquidity of the whole pool for the same price range.
When I compare these, my liquidity is about 0.0185% of the pool's liquidity.
However, when I look at the USD values, my position is about 0.111% of the pool's USD value.
Concrete example:
Block: 20773531
Tick range: 198730 to 198830 (prices ~2319 to ~2342)
Current adjusted tick: 198780 (price ~2328)
Total USD locked in this range: ~2,096,710
Total liquidity in this range: 8.702107653779109e+19

My position:
amount0 = 1
amount1 = 2328
current_price = 2328
price_a = 2319
price_b = 2342

Calculated liquidity: 16118693898347210
Calculations:
Liquidity ratio: (16118693898347210 / 8.702107653779109e+19) * 100 ≈ 0.0185%
USD value ratio: (2328 / 2096710) * 100 ≈ 0.111%
Question:
Why is there such a large discrepancy between these two ratios? My liquidity is 0.0185% of the pool's liquidity, but my USD value is 0.111% of the pool's USD value - about a 6x difference.
Shouldn't the liquidity ratio and the USD value ratio be closer to each other? Am I misunderstanding something about how liquidity and dollar values relate in Uniswap V3?
Code:
Here's the relevant part of my liquidity calculation class:
#pool.q96 = 2**96
#taking out the func I use t oconvert ptice to sqrt of price in q96
def price_to_sqrt_price_x96(
        self, price: float, token0_decimals: int, token1_decimals: int
    ) -> int:
        """
        Convert a price (token1/token0) to sqrtPriceX96 format
        """
        price_adjusted = price * (10 ** (token0_decimals - token1_decimals))
        return int(np.sqrt(price_adjusted) * (2**96))

class FullMath:
    @staticmethod
    def mul_div(a: int, b: int, denominator: int) -> int:
        return a * b // denominator

class LiquidityPeriphery:
    def __init__(self, pool):
        self.pool = pool

    def get_liquidity_for_amount0(self, price_a: int, price_b: int, amount0: int) -> int:
        if price_a > price_b:
            price_a, price_b = price_b, price_a
        intermediate = FullMath.mul_div(price_a, price_b, self.pool.q96)
        return FullMath.mul_div(amount0, intermediate, price_b - price_a)

    def get_liquidity_for_amount1(self, price_a: int, price_b: int, amount1: int) -> int:
        if price_a > price_b:
            price_a, price_b = price_b, price_a
        return FullMath.mul_div(amount1, self.pool.q96, price_b - price_a)

    def get_liquidity_for_amounts(self, price, price_a, price_b, amount0, amount1):
        if price_a > price_b:
            price_a, price_b = price_b, price_a

        if price <= price_a:
            liquidity = self.get_liquidity_for_amount0(price_a, price_b, amount0)
        elif price < price_b:
            liquidity0 = self.get_liquidity_for_amount0(price, price_b, amount0)
            liquidity1 = self.get_liquidity_for_amount1(price_a, price, amount1)
            liquidity = min(liquidity0, liquidity1)
        else:
            liquidity = self.get_liquidity_for_amount1(price_a, price_b, amount1)

        return liquidity

    def calculate_liquidity(self, amount0, amount1, current_price, price_a, price_b):
        # Convert price to sqrt price x96
        price = self.pool.price_to_sqrt_price_x96(current_price, self.pool.decimals0, self.pool.decimals1)
        price_a = self.pool.price_to_sqrt_price_x96(price_a, self.pool.decimals0, self.pool.decimals1)
        price_b = self.pool.price_to_sqrt_price_x96(price_b, self.pool.decimals0, self.pool.decimals1)

        # Scale the amounts by decimal points
        amount0 = amount0 * (10**self.pool.decimals1)
        amount1 = amount1 * (10**self.pool.decimals0)

        # Calculate liquidity
        return self.get_liquidity_for_amounts(price, price_a, price_b, amount0, amount1)
    ``` 


Tokens with the same value contribute differently to the pool's liquidity

depending on how wide or narrow the position is;
depending on their position in the pool relative to the current price.

For instance, the same amount of $ is going to give you one liquidity if deposited near the current price, but 2 times larger liquidity if deposited at a price 4 times higher / lower than the current price, for a position with the same width (in ticks).
Your numbers could be correct, at least there's no obvious problems. The reason for the observed discrepancy is that your liquidity is more concentrated than the average liquidity. It also may be closer to the current price compared with the average liquidity position in the pool.

Thanks for the response. It makes sense that the liqudity increases with position. But what does not make sense to me is that for the same tick width I provide liqudity of 0.0185% when compared to the liqudidty in the same ticks range. But when I take just the dollar amounts of what I provide compared to the converted dollar amount in the same tick width I get much higher %. For some reason I thought they should be closer. Also I can use that liquidity to calculate % of share from fees at any tick in my range? Btw appreciate your articles!

@Sammm fees are given proportional to the liquidity, not the dollar value

For some reason I thought they should be closer I'd expect this too, something feels dodgy here
